# I keep getting the error "String Index out of range" I have made sure that the array has enough indices. Can anyone see the problem?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, range

Here is the code. Can anyone spot the error?

```
file = open("WSJ_02-21.pos-chunk", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
input_list = [[0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(len(lines))]
for i in range(len(input_list)):
    input_line = lines[i].split("\t")
    if len(input_line) == 0:
        for j in range(len(input_list[i])):
            input_list[i][j] = ""
    elif len(input_line) == 3:
        for j in range(len(input_list[i])):
            input_list[i][j] = input_line[i][j]
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/inigo/PycharmProjects/NLPHW5/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    input_list[i][j] = input_line[i][j]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

My expected output is a 2 dimensional list with the elements WSJ_02-21.pos-chunk

link to the input file
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QLMfD9HhvshhqE7XqIn96ML-M0j2uNLh/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: pls post the full traceback, expected output and actual output

Comment: It works fine for me. Could you share your input file?

Comment: `[0 for j in range(5)]` is expressed more simply as `[0]*5` Also, errors like this are sometimes traceable to having an empty line in the file. That is just a guess -- since you have neglected to provide us with enough information to do anything more than guess.

Comment: @JohnColeman what information do you need?

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve]. Please make it self-contained (not dependent on external links). `lines = file.readlines()` makes your `lines` a list of strings that we have no knowledge of. Perhaps you can create a minimal example file which has the problem and literally post the list of strings `lines` in your question.

Comment: @JohnColeman at the bottom of the post I have put the link to the input file

Comment: How is a link to a file a [mcve] which doesn't depend on external links?

Comment: The file is over 17,000 words long I am not sure how to put that in a stack overflow post. Also you just made up the links part that is nowhere in that article.

Comment: Note the word "minimal" in [mcve]. Please read that Stack Overflow help article if you haven't done so already. The idea isn't to post your whole data -- but a carefully chosen subset that illustrates the problem.

Comment: The article says that a [mcve] should be "Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself". If following an external link is needed to reproduce the problem, then it isn't complete in the question itself. Links can grow stale and also raise security concerns.

Comment: By the way -- your code crashes when `i = 1`, so you aren't parsing the very first non-blank line the way you want to. Do you really want `input_list[i][j] = input_line[i][j]`? When you look at how `input_line` is defined, this is really `input_list[i][j] = lines[i].split("\t")[i][j]` and the two `i` on the right-hand side seem suspicious.

Comment: Could you explain more on the goal of the code? It seems like you intended to create an `input_list` that contains characters from any line that has three substrings separated by `\t` but the condition `len(input_line) == 3` means that if `i` >= 3 (any line after the third line), you would get index error when accessing `input_line[i]` and if `len(input_line[i])` is less than 5 then there would also be index error when accessing `input_line[i][j]` since `for j in range(len(input_list[i]))` always iterating from 0 to 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the code isn't completely clear, but if I understand it correctly the following code seems to be what you are trying to achieve:

```
with open("WSJ_02-21.pos-chunk", 'r') as f:
    input_list = []
    for line in f:
        input_line = line.strip().split('\t')
        if len(input_line) == 0:
            input_list.append([''])
        elif len(input_line) == 3:
            input_list.append(input_line)
```

But -- do you really want to have entries for blank lines?

If not, the following might be even better:

```
with open("WSJ_02-21.pos-chunk", 'r') as f:
    input_list = []
    for line in f:
        input_line = line.strip()
        if len(input_line) > 0:
            input_list.append(input_line.split('\t'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line you pass is like:

```
lines = ["avd\tbdc\tcdc"]
```

Your `input_line` will have 3 tokens (hence will end up in the `elif`) but your `input_list[i]` will be longer than 5 (the default length you imposed in each line of `input_list`) and you'll end up out of range

```
input_list[i][j] = input_line[i][j]
IndexError: string index out of range
```